How to use Proguard code obfuscation with Compose Desktop?
I'm going to build a compose desktop application using compose multiplatform framework and wanted to obfuscate code using ProGuard. And on their GitHub page, they also had a tutorial about ways to obfuscate and optimize code in release build. I changed my build.gradle.kts file according to their instruction:
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    alias(libs.plugins.composeCompiler)
}

kotlin {
    jvm("desktop")

    sourceSets {
        val desktopMain by getting

        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.runtime)
            implementation(compose.foundation)
            implementation(compose.material3)
            implementation(compose.ui)
            implementation(compose.components.resources)
            implementation(compose.components.uiToolingPreview)
        }
        desktopMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
        }
    }
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "com.dangxuanthong.composedesktopproguard"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }

        buildTypes.release.proguard {
            obfuscate.set(true)
        }
    }
}

Then I went ahead and used this command: ./gradlew createReleaseDistributable but instead of creating an optimized .msi file it printed out this error log:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Type-safe project accessors is an incubating feature.

> Task :composeApp:proguardReleaseJars
ProGuard, version 7.2.2
Unexpected error
java.io.IOException: Can't read [D:\LapTrinh\Kotlin\Compose Desktop With Proguard\composeApp\build\libs\composeApp-desktop.jar] (Can't process class [AppKt.class] (Unsupported version number [65.0] (maximum 62.65535, Java 18)))
        at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:269) ~[proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:233) ~[proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:210) ~[proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:140) ~[proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.pass.PassRunner.run(PassRunner.java:24) ~[proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:309) ~[proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:111) ~[proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:623) [proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't process class [AppKt.class] (Unsupported version number [65.0] (maximum 62.65535, Java 18))
        at proguard.io.ClassReader.read(ClassReader.java:118) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:85) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.io.RenamedDataEntryReader.read(RenamedDataEntryReader.java:97) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:85) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:85) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:84) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.io.DirectorySource.readFiles(DirectorySource.java:68) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.io.DirectorySource.pumpDataEntries(DirectorySource.java:54) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:265) ~[proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported version number [65.0] (maximum 62.65535, Java 18)
        at proguard.classfile.util.ClassUtil.checkVersionNumbers(ClassUtil.java:167) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:?]
        at proguard.classfile.io.ProgramClassReader.visitProgramClass(ProgramClassReader.java:117) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:?]
        at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:544) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:?]
        at proguard.io.ClassReader.read(ClassReader.java:95) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:85) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.io.RenamedDataEntryReader.read(RenamedDataEntryReader.java:97) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:85) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.io.FilteredDataEntryReader.read(FilteredDataEntryReader.java:85) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.io.JarReader.read(JarReader.java:84) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.io.DirectorySource.readFiles(DirectorySource.java:68) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.io.DirectorySource.pumpDataEntries(DirectorySource.java:54) ~[proguard-core-9.0.1.jar:7.2.2]
        at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:265) ~[proguard-base-7.2.2.jar:7.2.2]
        ... 7 more

> Task :composeApp:proguardReleaseJars FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':composeApp:proguardReleaseJars'.
> External tool execution failed:
  * Command: [C:\DevTools\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe, -cp, "C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.guardsquare\\proguard-gradle\\7.2.2\\3ee8f512db2b
ee70d3eca9be10986d96404dc2f0\\proguard-gradle-7.2.2.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.github.zafarkhaja\\java-semver\\0.9.0\\59a83ca73c72
a5e25b3f0b1bb305230a11000329\\java-semver-0.9.0.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.guardsquare\\proguard-base\\7.2.2\\5c67dd9184bfb7d01b08
2b45bf3a6599b43d5c25\\proguard-base-7.2.2.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.jetbrains.kotlin\\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\\1.6.10\\e80fe6ac3c3573a
80305f5ec43f86b829e8ab53d\\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.10.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.google.code.gson\\gson\\2.8.5\\f645ed69d595b24d4cf
8b3fbb64cc505bede8829\\gson-2.8.5.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.guardsquare\\proguard-core\\9.0.1\\b1c26f3a6fc947a1bdfa67fd8c96230df0
471156\\proguard-core-9.0.1.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.apache.logging.log4j\\log4j-core\\2.17.1\\779f60f3844dadc3ef597976fcb1e5127
b1f343d\\log4j-core-2.17.1.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.apache.logging.log4j\\log4j-api\\2.17.1\\d771af8e336e372fb5399c99edabe0919ae
af5b2\\log4j-api-2.17.1.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.json\\json\\20211205\\47032dcf2f69880f07dab3dc60b4b0ad97318308\\json-20211205.j
ar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.jetbrains.kotlin\\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\\1.6.10\\e1c380673654a089c4f0c9f83d0ddfdc1efdb498\\kotlin-stdlib-jd
k7-1.6.10.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.jetbrains.kotlinx\\kotlinx-metadata-jvm\\0.4.1\\834f5bdb32c504ee72fa50750ad16ab1679c19e6\\kot
linx-metadata-jvm-0.4.1.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.jetbrains.kotlin\\kotlin-stdlib\\1.6.10\\b8af3fe6f1ca88526914929add63cf5e7c5049
af\\kotlin-stdlib-1.6.10.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.jetbrains.kotlin\\kotlin-stdlib-common\\1.6.10\\c118700e3a33c8a0d9adc920e9dec0
831171925\\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.10.jar;C:\\Users\\Admin\\.gradle\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\org.jetbrains\\annotations\\13.0\\919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a
2672a9\\annotations-13.0.jar", proguard.ProGuard, -include, "D:\\LapTrinh\\Kotlin\\Compose Desktop With Proguard\\composeApp\\build\\compose\\tmp\\proguardReleaseJars\\root-config.pro"]
  * Working dir: []
  * Exit code: 1
  * Standard output log: D:\LapTrinh\Kotlin\Compose Desktop With Proguard\composeApp\build\compose\logs\proguardReleaseJars\java-2024-07-21-09-49-03-out.txt
  * Error log: D:\LapTrinh\Kotlin\Compose Desktop With Proguard\composeApp\build\compose\logs\proguardReleaseJars\java-2024-07-21-09-49-03-err.txt


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 22s
13 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 12 up-to-date

I am using Windows 10 22H2 with Java JDK 21. Here is my project repository: Github

This question is similar to: java.io.IOException: Can't process class [class path] (Unsupported version number [55.0] (maximum 54.0, Java 10)), respectively the question that is linked there. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
